# How to expand GROUP_CONCAT value?

Tags: php, mysql

```
SELECT
    `s1`.`question`,
    GROUP_CONCAT(QUOTE(`so1`.`name`)) `answers`
FROM
    `survey` `s1`
INNER JOIN
    `survey_option` `so1`
ON
    `so1`.`survey_id` = `s1`.`id`
GROUP BY
    `s1`.`id`;
```

This query will product `question` list with `answer` as a quoted-comma separated string.

How do I expand answer string into an array?

The first thing that comes to my mind is `explode("','", mb_substr($answers_str, 1, -1))`.

Are there any gotchas that I should be aware?

Comment: Why do you use GROUP_CONCAT() at all, if you don't want it like this?

Comment: You retrieve it in a single row and you can split it again on the client side @fancyPants

Comment: The point is, there's no need to. Like Strawberry said, don't group it and you're fine, no need to explode anything.

Comment: its easier to handle one question answer set per row.

Comment: @DevZer0 Consider my answer for instance. You can populate an array per `survey_id` if you so desire. You also don't have to worry about answers containing the separator (could be `,`) upon `explode`.

Comment: This is just based on Opinions of one another

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made this problem sound more difficult than it actually turned out to be. My solution does not directly answer my question, though it has solved the underlying issue.

I need to produce a data export for the reports portal where there is a set of defined variables (e.g. first_name, last_name, etc.) + data variables that vary throughout the time (i.e., must be either included or excluded depending on whether it exists in the defined time interval). Furthermore, it had to be produced in Excel friendly format (e.g. csv) (thus the first attempt using GROUP CONCATination using commas).

The solution that I went with is **dynamic query generation**.

```
public function getCombined/*[..]*/ (array $filter = []) {
    // Find the columns
    $freeform_data = $this->db
        ->prepare("
        SELECT
            DISTINCT `dpd1`.`name`
        FROM
            `device_product` `dp1`
        INNER JOIN
            `device_product_data` `dpd1`
        ON
            `dpd1`.`device_product_id` = `dp1`.`id`;
        ")
        ->execute([$filter)
        ->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);

    $freeform_data_selectors = '';
    $freeform_data_join = '';

    foreach ($freeform_data as $i => $name) {
        if ($name != preg_replace('/[^a-z_-]/i', '', $name)) {
            throw new \ErrorException('Invalid freeform data input name ("' . $name . '").');
        }

        $alias = '`dpd' . ($i + 1) . '`';

        $freeform_data_selectors .= ', ' . $alias . '.`value` `freeform_' . $name . '`';

        $freeform_data_join .= '
        LEFT JOIN
            `device_product_data` ' . $alias . '
        ON
            ' . $alias . '.`device_product_id` = `dp1`.`id` AND
            ' . $alias . '.`name` = \'' . $name . '\'
            ';
    }

    $stmt = $this->db
        ->prepare("
        SELECT
            `d1`.`mac_address` `device_mac_address`,            
            {$freeform_data_selectors}
        FROM
            `device_product` `dp1`          
        {$freeform_data_join}
        GROUP BY
            `dp1`.`id`;", [\PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY => false])
        ->execute($filter);

    return stmt;
}
```

This is a cut down example and it might seem similar to what Robin Castlin suggested. However, the actual query has another 10 joins and a large dataset (2M+). Castlin's suggestion would require far more resource to retrieve the data and organise it.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Run query
SELECT
#   `s1`.`id`,
    `s1`.`question`,
    `so1`.`name`
FROM
    `survey` `s1`
INNER JOIN
    `survey_option` `so1`
ON
    `so1`.`survey_id` = `s1`.`id`

# Fetch query
$arr = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($query))
    $arr[$row->question][] = $row->name;

# If question's aren't unique, you can also fetch 'id' in query and:
$arr = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($query))
    $arr[$row->id][] = $row;
```

This asumes that you save the query value as `$query`. There's no point in doing a `GROUP_CONCAT` if you plan to split them up afterwards. Simply using an array and it's key values is enough for that.

Comment: In my case, the system is meant to produce data reports based on dynamic-length user input. The data is stored using schema identical to the one in the example. Post-processing of the data as such is not going to work, or at least not in any efficient way.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean. I took the example in consideration and it should have the same data structure. Why wouldn't it be efficient to do it like that?